# Widget com previsão do tempo, não aparece na página?

Tags: javascript

Estou usando este site para geração do código para adicionar no site, após ter feito o processo solicitado, nada aparece, não gera erro, alguém sabe o que poderia está errado? Agradeço
https://www.climadobrasil.com.br/widget

Comment: Mostre o que você fez e descreva com detalhes a sua dificuldade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Não sei se compreendi seu problema mas eu consegui gerar normalmente pelo Google Chrome o seu código para a cidade de São Paulo, com as configurações que estavam na tela.

```
<div id="c_1bc68b4bece7478577e7f1eab6a90177" class="normal"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.clima.com/widget/widget_loader/1bc68b4bece7478577e7f1eab6a90177"></script>
```

Não apareceu nenhum erro também, mas o resultado ficou no rodapé da página:

[image: Imagem do código gerado]

Tentou o básico: trocar de navegador, usar uma cidade conhecida, desbloquear os pop-ups?

Atte,

Comment: Eu também fiz a geração do código sem erros, mais na página fica em branco.

Comment: "Tentou o básico: trocar de navegador, usar uma cidade conhecida, desbloquear os pop-ups?"

O que ocorre? Segue em branco?